# Property 'children' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]
I'm having a typescript error. It says that 'children' does not exist on type '{}' even though this syntax works on my other projects.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not defined a type for `React.FC`

The fix could be

```
type Props = {
   children: React.ReactNode
}

const Page: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  ...
}
```

Comment: **Thank you for answer, solved my problem.**

Before: 
export const PageLayout: React.FC<{}> = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            {props.children}
        </>
    );
};

After (React 18):
interface Props {
    children?: React.ReactNode | undefined
}
export const PageLayout: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <>
            {children}
        </>
    );
};

Answer (score 29):

I'm guessing this new app is on React 18.

React 18 removed `children` from the `FC` type. If you want it back you need to add it to the props yourself.

```
const Foo: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => <>{children}</>
```

Or preferably, don't use the `FC` type at all:

```
interface Props {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

function Foo({ children }: Props) {
    return<>{children}</>
}
```

Comment: Why would they remove it. Isn't that one of the main reasons for `React.FC` ???

Comment: You don't need to use `React.FC` at all. Just make a function that returns what you want to render.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by others, React 18 removed `children` from the props type definition.

You can do the following instead, by explicitly declaring your props should include children:

```
import { FunctionComponent, PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren> =
  ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;
```

The above would default the props to the `unknown` type.

You can also define the props:

```
import { FunctionComponent, PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

interface Props {
  label: string;
}

export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<PropsWithChildren<Props>> =
  ({ label, children }) => <div>{label}: {children}</div>;
```

Or even better:

```
import { FunctionComponent, PropsWithChildren } from 'react';

interface Props extends PropsWithChildren {
  label: string;
}

export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> =
  ({ label, children }) => <div>{label}: {children}</div>;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the destructured props argument by following

```
{ children }: {children: React.ReactNode}
```